# Dynamic adding data in one listview based into another listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter

i'm trying to add data into a listview2 based on a selected item from another lisview1, but somehow every time i select one item from listview1 my application crash exactly , can somebody help me?

Java CLASS

```
    package com.petridis.medral;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Equipe extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // php read comments script

    // localhost :
    // testing on your device
    // put your local ip instead, on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
    // or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
    // private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL =
    // "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice/comments.php";

    // testing on Emulator:
    private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL = "http://192.168.0.14:1234/webservice/comments.php";

    // testing from a real server:
    // private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL =
    // "http://www.mybringback.com/webservice/comments.php";

    // JSON IDS:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_NOME = "funcionarios";
    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "Funcionario";


    //Declarar search
    EditText inputSearch;

    // Array de JSON para buscar dados
    private JSONArray mComments = null;

    // manages all of our comments in a list.
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mCommentList;

    // Cria um array list

    //Cria um array adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList listaSelecionada = new ArrayList();;
    private StableArrayAdapter adapterZ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.team_build);
        // Crio uma listview e vinculo com o XML        
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);        
        String[] values = new String[] {};
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
          list.add(values[i]);
        }

        StableArrayAdapter adapterZ = new StableArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.single_post, list);
        listview.setAdapter(adapterZ);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        // loading the comments via AsyncTask
        new LoadComments().execute();
    }

    public void addComment(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Equipe.this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void updateJSONdata() {

        mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_COMMENTS_URL);

        try {

            mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_NOME);

            // Looping para pegar resultados
            for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);

                // Pegar o conteudo do tag
                String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);

                // Criar o HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_NOME, title);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                mCommentList.add(map);

                // annndddd, our JSON data is up to date same with our array
                // list
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the parsed data into the listview.
     */
    private void updateList() {
        // For a ListActivity we need to set the List Adapter, and in order to
        // do
        // that, we need to create a ListAdapter. This SimpleAdapter,
        // will utilize our updated Hashmapped ArrayList,
        // use our single_post xml template for each item in our list,
        // and place the appropriate info from the list to the
        // correct GUI id. Order is important here.
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mCommentList,
                R.layout.single_post, new String[] { TAG_NOME },
                new int[] { R.id.title });


        // I shouldn't have to comment on this one:
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // Optional: when the user clicks a list item we
        // could do something. However, we will choose
        // to do nothing...
        ListView lv = getListView();
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                Equipe.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                HashMap item = mCommentList.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(Equipe.this, item + "selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                listaSelecionada.add("Teste");
                adapterZ.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });
    }

    private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> objects) {
          super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
          for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
            mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
          }
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
          String item = getItem(position);
          return mIdMap.get(item);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
          return true;
        }

      }

    public class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Equipe.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Comments...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // we will develop this method in version 2
            updateJSONdata();
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // we will develop this method in version 2
            updateList();
        }
    }

}
```

team_build.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:background="#fff" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_layover"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Procurar funcionarios"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ListView_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_layover"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top_layover"
            android:weightSum="1" >

                <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_ListView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@android:id/list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:scrollbars="none" />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_ListView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#333"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/list2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list2"
                    android:scrollbars="none" />
                </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>        


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_layover"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/post_comment"
                    style="@style/WhiteText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:background="@drawable/black_button"
                    android:onClick="addComment"
                    android:text="@string/post_comment" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

single_post.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/post_border_style"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/box"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/post_background_style"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/box"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="6dip"
                    android:textColor="#333"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.petridis.medral"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.petridis.medral.Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.petridis.medral.Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.petridis.medral.Equipe"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LOGCAT

```
12-21 19:34:51.627: D/ProgressBar(1453): setProgress = 0
12-21 19:34:51.627: D/ProgressBar(1453): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
12-21 19:34:51.627: D/ProgressBar(1453): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
12-21 19:34:51.688: D/request!(1453): starting
12-21 19:34:51.698: D/ProgressBar(1453): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
12-21 19:34:51.698: D/ProgressBar(1453): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
12-21 19:34:51.698: D/ProgressBar(1453): updateDrawableBounds: right = 72
12-21 19:34:51.698: D/ProgressBar(1453): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 72
12-21 19:34:51.908: D/Login attempt(1453): {"message":"Login successful!","success":1}
12-21 19:34:51.908: D/Login Successful!(1453): {"message":"Login successful!","success":1}
12-21 19:34:53.550: D/AbsListView(1453): Get MotionRecognitionManager
12-21 19:34:53.560: D/AbsListView(1453): Get MotionRecognitionManager
12-21 19:34:53.570: D/ProgressBar(1453): setProgress = 0
12-21 19:34:53.570: D/ProgressBar(1453): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
12-21 19:34:53.570: D/ProgressBar(1453): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
12-21 19:34:53.600: D/AbsListView(1453): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
12-21 19:34:53.600: D/AbsListView(1453): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-21 19:34:53.600: D/AbsListView(1453): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
12-21 19:34:53.600: D/AbsListView(1453): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-21 19:34:53.600: D/AbsListView(1453): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
12-21 19:34:53.600: D/AbsListView(1453): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-21 19:34:53.600: D/AbsListView(1453): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
12-21 19:34:53.600: D/AbsListView(1453): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-21 19:34:53.630: D/ProgressBar(1453): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
12-21 19:34:53.630: D/ProgressBar(1453): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
12-21 19:34:53.630: D/ProgressBar(1453): updateDrawableBounds: right = 72
12-21 19:34:53.630: D/ProgressBar(1453): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 72
12-21 19:34:53.660: D/AbsListView(1453): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-21 19:34:53.660: D/AbsListView(1453): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-21 19:34:53.820: D/AbsListView(1453): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-21 19:34:53.820: D/AbsListView(1453): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-21 19:34:53.870: D/AbsListView(1453): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-21 19:34:53.870: D/AbsListView(1453): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-21 19:34:53.880: E/ViewRootImpl(1453): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
12-21 19:34:55.111: D/AndroidRuntime(1453): Shutting down VM
12-21 19:34:55.111: W/dalvikvm(1453): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d35ac8)
12-21 19:34:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(1453): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 19:34:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(1453): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-21 19:34:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at com.petridis.medral.Equipe$2.onItemClick(Equipe.java:199)
12-21 19:34:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
12-21 19:34:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1525)
12-21 19:34:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3297)
12-21 19:34:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4348)
12-21 19:34:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-21 19:34:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-21 19:34:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-21 19:34:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
12-21 19:34:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 19:34:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-21 19:34:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
12-21 19:34:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
12-21 19:34:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the entire log cat, There is is missing explanation in posted log cat, The issue is under the click method but your logcat is not explaining. The Caused By line is missing..

Comment: Please see my answer, this should fix the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring your adapter twice. One at class level and another one at function level in `onCreate`. When you try to access it on list item click it tries to access the adapter declared at class level which was never instantiated so returning null.

Change

```
StableArrayAdapter adapterZ = new StableArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.single_post, list);
```

to

```
adapterZ = new StableArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.single_post, list);
```